# ¿Como evitar que dentro de un ciclo for se me habran multiples sidebar de un componente hijo?

Tags: vue.js

Estoy trabajando por primera vez con componentes padres e hijos. Tengo ya la comunicación de respuesta y todo, pero tengo un problema al tener dentro de una tabla un botón que me abre un sidebar con la información del contacto

**Tabla padre**
Tengo un listado de, clientes y tiene un boton al final que es para visualizar datos del cliente, en vez de utilizar modal, utilize un sidebar.

```
                        <table class="table table-listbox table-bordered_ table-responsive-md table-striped_ text-center">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Contacto</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Proyecto</th>
                                    <th>Horas ocupadas</th>
                                    <th>Agentes encargados</th>
                                    <th>Acción</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-if="contacts.length === 0 && !loading">
                                    <td class="text-center" colspan="6">
                                        No hay contactos asociados a la empresa
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr v-if="loading">
                                    <td class="text-center" colspan="6">
                                        <b-spinner variant="primary" label="Spinning"></b-spinner>
                                        <b-spinner variant="primary" type="grow" label="Spinning"></b-spinner>
                                        <b-spinner variant="primary" label="Spinning"></b-spinner>
                                        <b-spinner variant="primary" type="grow" label="Spinning"></b-spinner>
                                        <b-spinner variant="primary" label="Spinning"></b-spinner>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr v-for="(contact,i) in contacts" :key="i">
                                    <td v-text="contact.name"></td>
                                    <td v-text="contact.email"></td>
                                    <td v-text="contact.project"></td>
                                    <td v-text="contact.hours"></td>
                                    <td v-text="contact.users"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <edit-contact :company_id="company" :contact="contact.id"></edit-contact> // Me abre si hay 5 datos en la tabla 5 veces el mismo sidebar
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

**Edit Contact**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-button variant="outline-primary" @click="openSideBarModal">Editar contacto</b-button>

        <b-sidebar
            id="edit-contacts-sidebar"
            width="700px"
            bg-variant="white"
            title="Nuevo Contacto"
            center
            right
            shadow
        >
            <b-card>
                <b-form @submit.prevent="onSubmitContact($event)" @reset="onReset">
                    <b-form-group label-cols="4" label-cols-lg="3" label-size="sm" label="Nombre completo" label-for="fullname">
                        <b-form-input id="fullname" v-model="contactForm.full_name" size="sm"></b-form-input>
                    </b-form-group>
                    <b-form-group label-cols="4" label-cols-lg="3" label-size="sm" label="Telefono contacto" label-for="phone">
                        <b-form-input id="phone" v-model="contactForm.phone" size="sm"></b-form-input>
                    </b-form-group>
                    <b-form-group label-cols="4" label-cols-lg="3" label-size="sm" label="Email" label-for="mail">
                        <b-form-input id="mail" v-model="contactForm.email" size="sm"></b-form-input>
                    </b-form-group>
                    <b-form-group label-cols="4" label-cols-lg="3" label-size="sm" label="Proyecto">
                        <v-select
                            v-model="selectedP"
                            :options="projects"
                            :getOptionLabel="opt => opt.name"
                            :getOptionKey="opt => opt.id"
                            placeholder="Seleccionar proyecto"
                            class="col-sm-12"
                            @option:selected="selectProject(selectedP)"
                        ></v-select>
                    </b-form-group>
                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Guardar</b-button>
                    </div>
                </b-form>
            </b-card>
        </b-sidebar>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ContactCreate',
    props: ['company_id','contact'],
    data() {
        return {
            contactForm: {
                full_name: '',
                phone:'',
                email:'',
                company_id: this.company_id,
                project_id: ''
            },
            selectedP: null,
            projects: [],
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getProjects()
    },
    methods: {
        openSideBarModal(){
            this.$root.$emit('bv::toggle::collapse', 'edit-contacts-sidebar')
        },
        getProjects(){
            axios.get(route('project.by_company',{client:this.contactForm['company_id']}))
                .then((res)=> {
                    this.projects = res.data
                })
        },
        selectProject(project){
        },
        onSubmitContact(event){

        },
    },

}
</script>
```

No se si me falta algo más para colocar un stop o no se, primera vez que hago esta relación, ya que si pongo el boton fuera del ciclo for funciona perfecto y abre una vez pero no se repite el boton en las demás columnas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ``<edit-contact>`` como sabe ese componente de qué contacto mostrar los datos? No deberias pasarle un ID al menos?

Comment: Por un prop ahi se le pasara ```<edit-contact :company_id="company" :contact="contact.id"></edit-contact>``` Pero aun sigue abriendome 2 veces el modal o 5 veces si el listado de la tabla tiene mas de 1 dato. Caso contrario sucede si es que hago que el sidebar no sea un componente externo y sea de la misma vista ya que la idea era unificar el componente Create y Editar pero no se abre 1 sola vez si no que n veces acorde al listado @AgustinG.

Comment: Creo q encontre tu problema. Tenes 5 elementos con el mismo ID. A cada edit contact, pasale ademas de esas props, una prop para el index del v-for (la que llamas ``i`` para el ``key="i"``). Entonces al id hacelo dinamico ``id=`edit-contacts-sidebar-${index}` ``

Comment: Por ultimo tenes que modificar la funcion openSideBarModal para pasarle como segundo parametro ``edit-contacts-sidebar-${index}`` en lugar de solo ``edit-contacts-sidebar``

Comment: bueno, ahi agregué una respuesta. En vez del indice podes usar ``contact`` y lo arreglas modificando dos lineas. Espero te sirva. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que tenes 5 elementos con el mismo id `edit-contacts-sidebar`

Tenes que hacer ese id dinamico. Podes usar `contact` que es el id de cada contacto, por lo que deberia ser unico.

```
<b-sidebar
    id=`edit-contacts-sidebar-${contact}`    
    ....
```

Y luego modificamor la funcion `openSideBarModal`

```
this.$root.$emit('bv::toggle::collapse', `edit-contacts-sidebar-${this.contact}`)
```